# How to convert tweet time to readable secs?

Tags: javascript, datetime, twitter, time

Here is an example of one of my tweet objects:

```
date: "2016-01-12T10:13:50Z"
formatted_date: "January 12, 2016 - 10:13 AM"
formatted_date_difference: "-20798 sec ago"
id: "68358314540"
link: true
literal_text: "One more mention of this: graphic novel night with DEATH theme. About 20 tickets remain. Come!... https://t.co/jInCQ2c8hv"
start_epoch: 1452615230
text: "One more mention of this: graphic novel night with DEATH theme. About 20 tickets remain. Come!... https://t.co/jInCQ2c8hv"
user_name: "watsoncomedian"
```

I'm trying to work with this `formatted_date_difference: "-20798 sec ago"`

So far I found this function from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108819/javascript-timestamp-to-relative-time-eg-2-seconds-ago-one-week-ago-etc-best).

```
function beautifyTime(timeAgo) {
    var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - timeAgo) / 1000),
    intervals = [
        Math.floor(seconds / 31536000),
        Math.floor(seconds / 2592000),
        Math.floor(seconds / 86400),
        Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
        Math.floor(seconds / 60)
    ],
    times = [
        'year',
        'month',
        'day',
        'hour',
        'minute'
    ];

    var key;
    for(key in intervals) {
        if (intervals[key] > 1)  
            return intervals[key] + ' ' + times[key] + 's ago';
        else if (intervals[key] === 1) 
            return intervals[key] + ' ' + times[key] + ' ago';
    }

    return Math.floor(seconds) + ' seconds ago';
}
```

However it always returns 49 years ago when I enter in `beautifyTime(16275);`  or `beautifyTime(20798)` as a test.

Comment: If you have a string saying `"-20798 sec ago"`, why do you need to put that through a function that should return `"20798 seconds ago"`, it seems  like just a little string replacement would do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it was made for it: [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks, that works :) I'm also going to post the factory I created from another answer that also worked for me

Comment: would you mind a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093347/moment-js-amdateformat-always-returning-date-from-1970 :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Angular service I created from the answer here: [JavaScript code to display Twitter created_at as xxxx ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549223/javascript-code-to-display-twitter-created-at-as-xxxx-ago)

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('tweetDateFactory', [])
        .factory('TweetDateFactory', factory);

    factory.$inject = [];

    function factory() {

        /** Init TweetDateFactory scope */
        /** ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
        var tweetDateFactory = {
            parseTwitterDate : parseTwitterDate
        }

        return tweetDateFactory;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        function parseTwitterDate(tdate) {
            var system_date = new Date(Date.parse(tdate));
            var user_date = new Date();
            if (K.ie) {
                system_date = Date.parse(tdate.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1'))
            }
            var diff = Math.floor((user_date - system_date) / 1000);
            if (diff <= 1) {return "just now";}
            if (diff < 20) {return diff + " seconds ago";}
            if (diff < 40) {return "half a minute ago";}
            if (diff < 60) {return "less than a minute ago";}
            if (diff <= 90) {return "one minute ago";}
            if (diff <= 3540) {return Math.round(diff / 60) + " minutes ago";}
            if (diff <= 5400) {return "1 hour ago";}
            if (diff <= 86400) {return Math.round(diff / 3600) + " hours ago";}
            if (diff <= 129600) {return "1 day ago";}
            if (diff < 604800) {return Math.round(diff / 86400) + " days ago";}
            if (diff <= 777600) {return "1 week ago";}
            return "on " + system_date;
        }

        // from http://widgets.twimg.com/j/1/widget.js
        var K = function () {
            var a = navigator.userAgent;
            return {
                ie: a.match(/MSIE\s([^;]*)/)
            }
        }();
    }
})();
```