# Moment.js amDateFormat always returning date from 1970

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timestamp, momentjs, angular-moment

**http://plnkr.co/edit/5zxXEEz30t51yGhgYWVF?p=preview**

I'm using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) in my app.

For some reason it's converting all my epoch timestamps to the same date from 1970.

[image]

`<td class="timespan">{{tag.added_epoch | amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'}}</td>`

This is what the `tag.added_epoch` value is `added_epoch: 1432252800`

However when I convert it online, I get the correct date:

[image]

Any idea why my filter is turning `1432252800` into **Saturday, January 17th 1970**?

Comment: Have you tried `moment.unix()` in angular-moment it would be `<span am-time-ago="message.unixTime | amFromUnix">`

Comment: I get this error `Unknown provider: amFromUnixFilterProvider <- amFromUnixFilter` looks like I need to use a different version of the lib :( but are my numbers correct?

Comment: I've took a quick look at moment.js and I get 1970 if I just use `moment(1432252800)` I get the 1970 date with the `unix` method I get the 2015 date, so your numbers seem to be correct.
From the angular-moment docs: 
Note: To use amFromUnix, install angular-moment version 1.0.0-beta.3

Comment: @Arminmsg how? They don't have that build up :( https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/releases oh nvm found it on the CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.0-beta.3/angular-moment.min.js

Comment: @Arminmsg ok I got it looking better: http://plnkr.co/edit/5zxXEEz30t51yGhgYWVF?p=preview still need to format it however, but at least it looks like I'm getting the correct year in there finally.

Comment: The latest build is the 1.0.0-beta3, take a look at the label

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm just quickly summarizing the problem and solution.

Moment.js offers two different ways to create a date from a unix timestamp
`moment(1432252800)` and `moment.unix(1432252800)`.

Both start at the same time (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC) but `moment()` uses the number as milliseconds, which are around 17 days and `moment.unix()` uses seconds.

angular-moment supports the `amFromUnix` filter, see [source](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/blob/6e8cd1ee3b81c5045bb70b76e6b3cc6d87d8872c/angular-moment.js#L428)

You can use it the following way

```
<time am-time-ago="myDate|amFromUnix">
{{myDate|amFromUnix|amCalendar}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to write own filter, like this:

```
 newapp.filter("fromTimestamp", function(){
   return function(timestamp, format){
     return moment.unix(timestamp).format(format)
   }
 })
```

And use them

```
<p class="date">{{date | fromTimestamp:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY'}}</p>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrV94o?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! +1 that is super clean :) Arminmsg however did answer my exact question, but your solution may actually be used to replace our code.

Comment: @LeonGaban Thanks for +1)