# Moment date format always returning 01/01/1970 instead of actual date in angular application

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment

Please find attachment. The actual date is 03/06/2019 but the returning formate is always 01/01/1970. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

```
apiData.map(res => {
const startDate = moment(res.Issue_Date).format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
const endDate = moment(res. Expire_Date).format('DD/MMM/YYYY');});
```

**Note: I am getting the date from API call like this (Issue_Date: 20190603)**

Comment: can you please share the code?

Comment: Code updated. I am getting date format from API like this (Issue_Date: 20190603)

Comment: My be its similar to the following question. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093952/10293350](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093952/10293350)

Comment: @sagar I tried the above-mentioned solution but not work.

Comment: Please don't update the question with the answer. Instead post it as an answer in a separate post

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Issue_Date to the String type. You are passing in the number which is considered as Unix timestamp and therefore that's why you are getting the Jan 01 1970, **11:06:30** (20190603 milliseconds passed from Jan 01 1970, 00:00:00).

```
moment(res.Issue_Date.toString()); // or moment(`${res.Issue_Date}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
apiData.map(res => {
const startDate = moment(res.Issue_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
const endDate = moment(res. Expire_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MMM/YYYY');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is your issue date is getting passed as number format, so moment is calculating in milliseconds. 
Try this -

```
let temp = res.Issue_Date.toString();
const startDate = moment(temp ).format('DD/MMM/YYYY');
console.log(startDate)
```