# Creating javascript Date object from Twitter API date – cross-browser solution

Tags: javascript, date, twitter

I've got a big problem with Twitter API created_at date, which has got following format: `Tue Apr 18 07:24:05 +0000 2017` ... I want to create javascript Date object from that, but I'm not able to find cross-browser solution. What I've tried so far:

- `new Date(Date.parse(input.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1')));` – returns null in Safari
- `new Date((input || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," "));` – returns null in IE11
- moment.js library throws warning about deprecated method and falls back to javascript Date()

Can someone help me to figure it out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow these 2 links

[How to format Twitter/Facebook feed date with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132964/how-to-format-twitter-facebook-feed-date-with-javascript)

[JavaScript code to display Twitter created_at as xxxx ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549223/javascript-code-to-display-twitter-created-at-as-xxxx-ago)

OR USE [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com/)

```
> var tweetDate = 'Mon Dec 02 23:45:49 +0000 2013'; moment(tweetDate,
> 'dd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY', 'en');
```

Comment: great, first link works ... I've spent 2 hours on it :-/ ... but momentjs throws warning to console about using deprecated method and falling back to javascript Date, as I said

Comment: moment.js will not throw the deprecated method error if you include the format as shown in the answer.